# How to save images taken from dslr into the raspberry pi's sd card

Tags: python, sd-card

I'm working on a project which I need to take images automatically from a DSLR camera and should save it in the raspberry pi's SD card.

There was a tutorial it shows how to save the image into sd card on DSLR camera but that's not what I need because I need to get images saved on the raspberry pi's SD card for future image processing works.

So I should save the picture inside raspberry Pi's SD card. Please show me a tutorial or a guidance to get this done. I'm a complete beginner to this raspberry pi implementations.

I'm using py charm IDE for image processing and Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want your camera to save images to the SD card your pi operating system is on?
If you have a canon camera you might be able to use CHDK and change the save path, the best place to find out how to do this would be the CHDK forums: https://chdk.setepontos.com/index.php

Your SD card will have two partitions, one will be 40odd Mb and be for booting, the other will have the rest of your os. I think you'll need CHDK on the boot partition as that's the one the camera will read.

Is there a reason why you couldn't use two SD cards? Connect the cameras card to the pi with a usb card reader? A new card is not a massive cost and a guaranteed solution.

Craig

Answer (score 0):

I've done just this using [gphoto2](http://www.gphoto.org/). You can run the program from the cli, a gui, and there is also a Python wrapper [here](https://github.com/jim-easterbrook/python-gphoto2). The number of cameras supported is [quite large](http://www.gphoto.org/proj/libgphoto2/support.php). You can designate where you want the images to be saved to which includes downloading them to say, your raspberry pi.

Install from the command line:

```
sudo apt install gphoto2
```

Using the cli the command you need could be as simple as:

```
gphoto2 --capture-image-and-download
```

Note that installing the Python lib involves installing some additional libraries. The github page has the install process listed there.

I found the following [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1eAYxnSU2aw) on using gphoto2. Note that some of the issues the author notes at the beginning don't seem to be a problem any longer. Additionally, I would follow the instructions for installing the Python library on its github page. Good luck!